# Magento 2: How to disable cron jobs?

Tags: magento2, cronjobs

I want to disable some Cron jobs by group or specific cron tab in my staging environment because of some reason.

Please someone suggest me a solution, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see list of cronjob and modify it then you can use following commands

> crontab -l
>   
>   crontab -e

Comment: and then comment out the line that is for your site I presume?

Comment: yes it is agree!